# Vue.JS & Semanti-UI modal

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, vue.js, vuejs2, semantic-ui

In one of my vue components, I have a button that is supposed to open a [Semantic-UI modal](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/usage) as follows:

Template:

```
<template>
<div>
 ...
 <button type="button" @click="openModal()"> Open </button>
 <div class="ui modal" id="confirmMod">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
      Modal Title
    </div>
    <div class="image content">
      <div class="image">
        An image can appear on left or an icon
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        A description can appear on the right
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <div class="ui button">Cancel</div>
      <div class="ui button">OK</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Script:

```
<script>
  export default {
    ...
    methods: {
      openModal() {
        $('#confirmMod').modal('show')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

However, when I click on the button to open the modal, this error shows up in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
```

I've added jquery both in the html and as a plugin in webpack (I used vue-cli to intitialize the vue webpack boilerplate).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Solution found. For those who have this issue, here is what to do:

1) Add jQuery as a plugin in your webpack config file:

```
plugins: [
    ...
    // JQUERY plugin
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    }),
    ...
]
```

2) Add semantic ui css/js at the top of your main.js (the file in which you init your Vue app):

```
import '../static/semantic/dist/semantic.css'
import '../static/semantic/dist/semantic.js'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
...
```

3) call the modal as you normally would in jquery: $('.ui.modal').modal()

I hope this helps.